# How can I load blank/NULL values with LOAD DATA INFILE from the MySQL command line

Tags: mysql

I am using the following command from the MySQL command line to try and import a csv file into one of my tables:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file path' INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(BASEID, BIGID, StartDate, EndDate)
```

Some of my rows have no value for `EndDate` which I want to be represented as `NULL` values in the database.

Unfortunately when I execute the above command I get the following error:

```
for column 'EndDate' at row 141lue:
```

If I remove the rows with blank cells the command works, so it is clearly the blank values for `EndDate` which are causing the problem.

I have also tried changing my csv file so that the blank cells say `NULL` or `\N`. I have also tried the following command instead but I still get the same error message:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file path' INTO TABLE Table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(BASEID, BIGID, StartDate, @EndDate)
SET EndDate = nullif(@EndDate, ' ')
```

**How can I load csv files which have some blank values?** The suggest solutions I have seen on other posts don't seem to work as outlined above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the issue that the `value` for the end date is missing, or that the *column* itself is missing?  These are not the same thing.  For the former case, I think `LOAD DATA` should be able to handle this, assuming that the target column for the end date can tolerate missing/null values.

What I suspect here is that some of your input lines look like this:

```
1,1,'2020-10-03'
```

That is, there is *no* fourth column present at all.  If this be the case, then the most prudent thing to do here might be to run a simple regex over your input CSV flat file to fix these missing fourth column edge cases.  You may try:

```
Find:    ^([^,]+,[^,]+,'[^,]+')$
Replace: $1,
```

This would turn the sample line above into:

```
1,1,'2020-10-03',
```

Now, the date value is still missing, but at least `LOAD DATA` should detect that the line has four columns, instead of just three.